# How to find the jacobian of $x= \textrm{e}^{u}-\cos v$ and $ y= \textrm{e}^{u}+\sin v. $

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the Jacobian of 
\begin{eqnarray}
x&=& \textrm{e}^{u}-\cos v \\
y&=& \textrm{e}^{u}+\sin v. 
\end{eqnarray}

Please help me with my homework, I don't know where to start!

Comment: Do you know what a jacobian is?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Just find the partial derivatives $$\mathcal J=\dfrac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}=\left|
\begin{matrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\ \,\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} 
\end{matrix}
\right|=\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v} -\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}.$$
And of course you know: $$\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}e^x=e^x\quad\color{grey}{\text{and}}\quad \dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\cos x=-\sin x\quad\color{grey}{\text{and}}\quad \dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\sin x=\cos x.$$